# Error handling using Python ftplib.all_errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, ftp, try-catch

I'm trying to extract useful error messages from the ftplib.all_errors, I'm catching `550 /dir.: No such file or directory` but I want to isolate whether it is an incorrect file or an incorrect directory. So far I have:

```
try: 

    //some code

except ftplib.all_errors,e:
     print(e)
```

Which is definetly not filtering the two.

Is there any *known* methods of doing this? I've been approaching this by searching the directory tree for a file that exists, but it was time expensive.

Comment: What is in the `try` block. Also the error seems unambiguous to me, you are trying to upload/download a resource that does not exists. You can't tell it's a file or directory if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to determine whether its exclusively an incorrect file or incorrect directory. Based on the following [FTP Statuses/Errors](http://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10142.aspx), there's no error that explicitly isolates a directory from an incorrect file. Best approach I see doing this, is first run the block in your `try` statement and if it returns the `550` error, use a backwards breadcrumbing approach to isolate the problem.